# Merge Sort | C++ - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

I thought I'd revise my concepts by coding some basic DS and Algos. After a great pace, I am kinda stuck now and not being able to identify my mistake.
I am getting a Segmentation Fault in the below code result. Any help would be great!

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void merge(int *arr, int s, int m, int e){
    int n1 = m-s, n2 = e-m+1;
    int L[n1], R[n2];
    for(int i=0; i<n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[s+i];
    for(int i=0; i<n2; i++)
        R[i] = arr[m+i];
    
    int p1 = 0, p2 = 0, k = s;
    while(p1<n1 && p2<n1){
        if(L[p1] <= R[p2])
            arr[k++] = L[p1++];
        else
            arr[k++] = R[p2++];
    }

    while(p1<n1)
        arr[k++] = L[p1++];
    while(p2<n2)
        arr[k++] = R[p2++];
    return;
}


void mergeSort(int *arr, int s, int e){
    if(s>=e) return;
    int m = (s+e)/2;
    mergeSort(arr, s, m-1);
    mergeSort(arr, m, e);
    merge(arr, s, m, e);
    return;
}
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin>>arr[i];
    mergeSort(arr, 0, n-1);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The best help would be your debugger, it would point you precisely where the fault occurs and you will be able to examine values of all variables at that moment. I'm afraid I cannot read your code, because I have no slightest idea what each of these one-letter variables means.

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Comment: ... and [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) and
[Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: probably n1 or n2 becomes zero at some point

Comment: It's actually easier to avoid off-by-one errors if you stick to the conventional half-open intervals.

Comment: That will crash if the input is large enough due to your use of arrays. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Look to your right! [New post formatting on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting?cb=1).

Comment: @Ted Yes it is :( Facebook's done a similar thing. It's like everybody has forgotten basic design principles. Or was it just not taught to the "new" generation?

Comment: I was getting an off-by-one error, I was trying to fetch the wrong index value in my array. Switched back to the conventional intervals to divide the array s->m & m+1->e

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Yeah, I switched to the old FB look and wrote a long comment about _why_ I did it. Fat chance anyone listens... :)

Comment: @RahulSharma You're getting a stackoverflow. Did you manage to fix it? I converted your code to standard C++ and used the `vector`s `at()` function to catch any errors in your indexing. This makes debugging simpler: https://pastebin.com/R74nZ4ew

Comment: FYI, professional coding guidelines say to always use `{` and `}` for `if`, `while`, `for`, `else` and `do-while`.  This will free you from some common, but hard to find, run-time defects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segmentation error is because you have an infinite recursion loop. There were some problems with the indices and one typo where you meant n2 but wrote n1.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void merge(int *arr, int s, int m, int e){
    int n1 = m-s+1, n2 = e-m;
    int L[n1], R[n2];

    for(int i=0; i<n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[s+i];
    for(int i=0; i<n2; i++)
        R[i] = arr[m+i+1];

    int p1 = 0, p2 = 0, k = s;
    while(p1<n1 && p2<n2){
        if(L[p1] <= R[p2])
            arr[k++] = L[p1++];
        else
            arr[k++] = R[p2++];
    }

    while(p1<n1)
        arr[k++] = L[p1++];
    while(p2<n2)
        arr[k++] = R[p2++];
    return;
}

void mergeSort(int *arr, int s, int e){
    if(s>=e) return;
    int m = (s+e)/2;
    mergeSort(arr, s, m);
    mergeSort(arr, m+1, e);
    merge(arr, s, m, e);
    return;
}

int main() {
    int n;

    cout << "Select value for N:";
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];

    cout << "Reading input:";
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];

    cout << "Your input is:" << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout << arr[i]<<" ";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Running merge sort" << endl;
    mergeSort(arr, 0, n-1);

    cout << "Final array:" << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```